# Is placing return statement before finally block a good practice?

Tags: java, return, try-catch, finally

I was wondering if below code is correct according to Java standards. Can return statement be placed after try block ? or is it always good to place return statement in finally block. Please help me out on this

```
public int method()
{
    try{
        //code
        return 1;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return 0;
    }
    finally{
    }
}
```

Comment: Placing it in finally is good practice. Since finally should be executed every time even any exception has occur or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting `return` in the `try` or even in the `catch`es is absolutely fine: do whatever is clearest. Take care not to discard too many exceptions though, particularly `java.lang.Throwable` as doing that can interfere with the workings of the JVM.

Note that if you have a `return` *in* the `finally` block, then the expression in the other `return` is *still* evaluated but the result is discarded and the return value in the `finally` block is returned back to the caller. Because of this, putting a `return` value in the `finally` block is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Finally is basically used for cleaning the resources in an application.
If finally block is present in the code,It is always executed even if no exception is catched.
You can place return statement after try block.It will be executed when no exception is catched.

Answer (score 0):

Bathsheba has explained it well. Adding to it even if you are placing return statement the control will not go back and when final block is executed then you control goes back. And if you are writing return in final block as explained it will override the previous return statements.